# Is there opposite single word to ‘enunciate’?

Tags: single-word-requests

Further to my previous question about the meaning of the word, ‘crisis an hour mentality,’ there was the following line in the article of Washington Post under the title, “For Obama, and Democrats, it’s crunch time.”

> “His mea culpa was all the more notable because it came only a few
>   days after he had attempted to put a retrospective asterisk on those
>   original assurances, **enunciated** as he sought to sell his controversial
>   health-care plan to a skeptical public.

According to Oxford Advanced Learners’ Dictionary, the word ‘enunciate’ means ‘to say or pronounce words **clearly**.

Is there opposite single word(s) (e.g. mumble) to say ‘to say or pronounce words **unclearly**?

Comment: You've answered your own question there: 'mumble' works, as does 'slur' (the latter only transitively, though).

Comment: Note that this particular usage does not refer to articulation, but rather to the other senses of [_enunciate_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enunciate): “To state or set forth precisely or systematically” or “To announce; proclaim.” For the sense you refer to, _mumble_ is a good antonym.

Comment: I think this is ***Unclear***. There are various possible antonyms to *enunciate*, but few could possibly be used in the given context (where *implied* is probably as good as any).

Comment: To pronounce __un__ clearly = to mumble. To explain _un_ clearly = to obfuscate, to confuse, to explain badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can find would be mispronounce, but that has to do with pronunciation, so it obviously isn't the answer. Denunciate means to condemn. Annunciate has to do with announcing something. E as a prefix is a variation of Ex-, meaning out. I'm starting to see some similarities here. Possibly, the word we could use would be Non-enunciate or disenunciate. Nonenunciate seems like the better answer as Non means not. I've been researching for quite a bit now and it seems that there is no invented word for the opposite of enunciation. There was a result for the Urban Dictionary when I searched disenunciate on Google, but I'm not comfortable with using the Urban Dictionary for references on this website.

TL;DR:
No, there is not a single opposite word for 'enunciate.' But, you can put prefixes in front of it and people likely will understand.

Answer (score 1):

When you enunciate, then there are no issues with the speech.  When you don't enunciate there can be an array of issues with the word.

- stammer
- stutter
- mispronounce
- slur
- lisp
- mumble
- bumble
- garble
- low talk